# Organizing data based on date in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date, dataset, pivot

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
 Category    Date
 --------    ----
 Backlog     7/18/18
 Backlog     7/18/18
 Testing     7/18/18
 Done        7/18/18
 Backlog     7/19/18
 Develop     7/19/18
 Backlog     7/20/18
 Done        7/20/18
 Done        7/20/18
```

That I want to transform by counting/organizing into this:

```
 Backlog     Testing    Develop    Done     Date
 -------     -------    -------    ----     ----
    2           1          0        1      7/18/18
    2           0          1        0      7/19/18
    1           0          0        2      7/20/18
```

However, the original data set continues to update everyday with a new date. The next day, several new rows will be added to the table with Backlog/Develop/Testing/Done tags with the date 7/21/18. How can I create this transformation in sql, while still taking in account the fact that the dataset updates everyday?

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in the presentation layer/application-level code, assuming you have that (e.g. a simple PHP loop acting upon an ordered array).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need *conditional* aggregation :

```
select sum(Category = 'Backlog') as Backlog, 
       sum(Category = 'Testing') as Testing,
       sum(Category = 'Develop') as Develop,
       sum(Category = 'Done') as Done,
       date
from table t
group by date;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from 
(
  select  Category,count(Category) as Total,Date
  from yourTableName group by Date,Category
) src
pivot
(
  sum(total)
  for Category in ([Backlog],[DONE],[Testing])
) piv;
```

Out put will be like this:

```
Date1       Backlog DONE    Testing
2018-07-18  2       1        1
2018-07-19  2       NULL    NULL
2018-07-20  NULL    2       NULL
```